# getting a java.lang.nullpointerexception error and cant find it

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Here is an app that I am making to keep score for spades and eventually other card games.  I am getting a null pointer exception error and am not sure where it is or what is wrong.  Thanks for any help anyone can give.

here is my java file

```
package com.innovativesolutions.cardscorekeeper;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int scorea, scoreb, takea[], takeb[], bida[], bidb[], baga, bagb, iii;
    EditText bidaa, bidbb, actuala, actualb, totala, totalb;
    Button total;
    CheckBox nila, nilb, gnila, gnilb;

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        iii = 0;
        baga = 0;
        bagb = 0;
        scorea = 0;
        scoreb = 0;
        total = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bidaa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.abid);
        bidbb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bbid);
        actuala = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.atake);
        actualb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.btake);
        totala = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.atotal);
        totalb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.btotal);
        nila = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.anil);
        nilb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.bnil);
        gnila = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.agnil);
        gnilb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.bgnil);
        total.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                bida[iii]=Integer.parseInt(bidaa.getText().toString());
                bidb[iii]=Integer.parseInt(bidbb.getText().toString());
                takea[iii]=Integer.parseInt(actuala.getText().toString());
                takeb[iii]=Integer.parseInt(actualb.getText().toString());


                if (nila.isChecked()){
                    if (gnila.isChecked() && takea[iii]>=bida[iii]){
                    baga = takea[iii]-bida[iii]+baga;
                    scorea = scorea + 100 + (bida[iii]*10);
                    } 
                    else {scorea = scorea - 100 - (bida[iii]*10);}
                } else {
                    if (takea[iii]>=bida[iii]){
                        baga = takea[iii]-bida[iii]+baga;
                        scorea = scorea + (bida[iii]*10);
                    } else {scorea = scorea - (bida[iii]*10);}

                }

                if (nilb.isChecked()){
                    if (gnilb.isChecked() && takeb[iii]>=bidb[iii]){
                    bagb = takeb[iii]-bidb[iii]+bagb;
                    scoreb = scoreb + 100 + (bidb[iii]*10);
                    } else {scoreb = scoreb - 100 - (bidb[iii]*10);}
                } else {
                    if (takeb[iii]>=bidb[iii]){
                        bagb = takeb[iii]-bidb[iii]+bagb;
                        scoreb = scoreb + (bidb[iii]*10);
                    } else {scoreb = scoreb - (bidb[iii]*10);}

                }               


                if (baga>=10){
                    scorea = scorea - 100;
                    baga = 0;
                }
                if (bagb>=10){
                    scoreb = scoreb - 100;
                    bagb = 0;
                }

                iii++;
                totala.setText(scorea);
                totalb.setText(scoreb);

        }
        });


            }}
```

and here is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Spades" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rook" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="Team A"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="Team B"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:text="Add Round" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:text="Bid"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Taken"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/abid"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/bbid"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/btake"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bbid"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/anil"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/abid"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/abid"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/abid"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="Nil?" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/bnil"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/bbid"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bbid"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Nil?" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/bgnil"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btake"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btake"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Nil?" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/atake"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/abid"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/agnil"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/atake"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/atake"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="Nil?" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/btotal"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/atotal"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/atotal"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="0" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/atotal"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/atake"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="0" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: provide the full stack trace please.

Comment: Please add the logcat also .

Comment: Paste Logcat to Intrude the Problem

Comment: Please post the logcat output. Are you getting exception on total's click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just you need to initalize all the arrays on integer which you have declared.
Initialize all this in your `onCreate()` as below:

> ```
>    @Override
>     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>     iii = 0;
>     baga = 0;
>     bagb = 0;
>     scorea = 0;
>     scoreb = 0;
>     bida=new int[10];
>     bidb=new int[10];
>     takea=new int[10];
>     takeb=new int[10];
>     ........................
>  }
> ```

Also parse the value of integer to set in the `TextView` as below:

> ```
>           totala.setText(String.valueOf(scorea));
>             totalb.setText(String.valueOf(scoreb));
> ```

Comment: thanks, that was the problem.  Still learning a lot of the basics lol

Answer (score 0):

this NPE are in below lines.

```
            bida[iii]=Integer.parseInt(bidaa.getText().toString());
            bidb[iii]=Integer.parseInt(bidbb.getText().toString());
            takea[iii]=Integer.parseInt(actuala.getText().toString());
            takeb[iii]=Integer.parseInt(actualb.getText().toString());
```

you have not defined size of these arrays names as

> takea[], takeb[], bida[], bidb[]

just doing below wont work. you need to assing size for these arrays. then only it will work

> int  takea[], takeb[], bida[], bidb[];

do something like `bida = new int[10];`

before u start using them.  // size will depends on what ur requirement is.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
total.onClickListener()
```

you are doing this

```
bida[iii]=Integer.parseInt(bidaa.getText().toString());
bidb[iii]=Integer.parseInt(bidbb.getText().toString());
takea[iii]=Integer.parseInt(actuala.getText().toString());
takeb[iii]=Integer.parseInt(actualb.getText().toString());
```

I don't see any initialization for these integer arrays. These are null by the time you are assigning values to these. Initialize in onCreate or in declaration.